# Envio de email via php não funciona

Tags: php

Estou a usar o mesmo script que já usei em outros sites mas parece que este site não está a enviar emails.

Se eu enviar um email através do painel de controlo virtual min o email é recebido no outlook no spam mas no gmail nem chega a chegar.

O que devo fazer?

```
       <?php


    $subject = "example";
    $from ='example@dominio.tk';
    $to ='<example@gmail.com>';
    $bcc = null; // Esconder endereços de e-mails.
    $cc = null; // Qualquer destinatário pode ver os endereços de e-mail especificados nos campos To e Cc.
    $message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
        width:100%;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
       background-color:#fff;
    }
    table#t01 th    {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <table id='t01'>
      <tr>
        <th>Lisguagens uteis</th>
        <th>Sites</th>
        <th>Prioridade</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>http://www.w3schools.com/</td>
        <td>1</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>http://www.w3schools.com/</td>
        <td>2</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>JAVASCRIPT</td>
        <td>https://codecademy.com/learn/javascript</td>
        <td>3</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PHP</td>
        <td>https://external.codecademy.com/learn/php</td>
        <td>4</td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='t01'>
      <tr>
      <th>Nota:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>text exemple</th>
      </tr>
    </body>
    </html>";

    $headers = sprintf( 'Date: %s%s', date( "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ), PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Return-Path: %s%s', $from, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'To: %s%s', $to, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Cc: %s%s', $cc, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Bcc: %s%s', $bcc, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'From: %s%s', $from, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Reply-To: %s%s', $from, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Message-ID: <%s@%s>%s', md5( uniqid( rand( ), true ) ), $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ], PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'X-Priority: %d%s', 3, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'X-Mailer: PHP/%s%s', phpversion( ), PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Disposition-Notification-To: %s%s', $from, PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'MIME-Version: 1.0%s', PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit%s', PHP_EOL );
    $headers .= sprintf( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"%s', PHP_EOL );

    mail(null, $subject, $message, $headers);







    echo("enviado");
?>
```

Comment: Adicione seu script na pergunta.

Comment: O primeiro parâmetro da função "mail" é o destinatário, você está passando null para ele.

Comment: mas estou a passar nos headers, de qualquer uma das formas se eu colocar lá a variável que contêm o e-mail ele continua se enviar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, você deve passar mais um parametro, o "remetente", nesse quinto parâmetro deve ser colocado algum email de sua empresa ou domínio por exemplo:
**-femail.address@example.com**
assim como está no Manual do PHP:

```
<?php mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-femail.address@example.com"); ?>
```

OBS: O manual do PHP explica porque usar o **-f**

> "Currently my hosting service is on Godaddy. When attempting to use
>   the mail function without the fifth parameter containing "-f", my
>   message headers would not work. "

Em uma tradução livre:

"Meu host é Godaddy. quando tento usar a função mail sem o quinto parâmetro com **-f** meus emails não funcionam"

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php

Sem esse quinto domínio, ele enviará com um email "estranho" que o google, por exemplo, considera malicioso.

Certifique-se de está testando fora do localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
<?php
$subject = "example"; //Assunto
$from ='example@adota-me.tk'; //Email de quem está enviando
$to ='example@gmail.com'; //Email de quem vai receber

$message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
        width:100%;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
       background-color:#fff;
    }
    table#t01 th    {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <table id='t01'>
      <tr>
        <th>Lisguagens uteis</th>
        <th>Sites</th>
        <th>Prioridade</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>http://www.w3schools.com/</td>
        <td>1</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>http://www.w3schools.com/</td>
        <td>2</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>JAVASCRIPT</td>
        <td>https://codecademy.com/learn/javascript</td>
        <td>3</td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PHP</td>
        <td>https://external.codecademy.com/learn/php</td>
        <td>4</td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='t01'>
      <tr>
      <th>Nota:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>text exemple</th>
      </tr>
    </body>
    </html>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n"; // remetente
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from\r\n"; // return-path

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-r".$from);
?>
```

Comment: Testei agora e não funcionou